# How to use DefineProperties in a custom Class Object for dynamic Arrays - Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to create my own class object and use it to store various data types for my application, this all works fine when using Published Properties, I can stream these to disk and back with no problems. But I need to stream some **dynamic** Arrays of integer types as well.

```
            type
              TArrayOfInteger = array of integer;

              TSetting = class(TComponent)
              private
                fIntVal: integer;
                fIntArr: TArrayOfInteger;
                procedure ReadIntArr(Reader: TReader);
                procedure WriteIntArr(Writer: TWriter);
              protected
                procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
              published
                property intval: integer read fIntVal write fIntVal;
                property intArr: TArrayOfInteger read fIntArr write fIntArr;
              end;

            { TSetting }

            procedure TSetting.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
            begin
              inherited;
              Filer.DefineProperty('intArr', ReadIntArr, WriteIntArr, true);
            end;
            procedure TSetting.ReadIntArr(Reader: TReader);
            var
              i: integer;
              lvVal:Integer;
            begin
              i:=low(fintArr);
              Reader.ReadListBegin;
              {j := Reader.ReadInteger();
              setlength(fIntArr, j);
              for i := 0 to j - 1 do
              begin
                fIntArr[i] := Reader.ReadInteger();
              end;}
            while not Reader.EndOfList do begin
                fIntArr[i]:=Reader.ReadInteger;
                Inc(i);
              end;
              Reader.ReadListEnd;
            end;

            procedure TSetting.WriteIntArr(Writer: TWriter);
            var
              i: integer;
            begin
              Writer.WriteListBegin;
              //Writer.WriteInteger(integer(Length(fIntArr)));
              for i := Low(fIntArr) to High(fIntArr) do
              begin
                Writer.WriteInteger(fIntArr[i]);
              end;
              Writer.WriteListEnd;
            end;

            function ClassToStr(pvClass:TComponent):ansiString;
            var
              inStream, outStream: TMemoryStream;

            begin
              inStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
              outStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
              try
                inStream.WriteComponentRes(pvClass.ClassName, pvClass);
                //inStream.WriteComponent(pvClass);
                inStream.Position := 0;
               ObjectResourceToText(inStream, outStream);
               // ObjectBinaryToText(inStream,outStream);
                outStream.Position := 0;
                SetLength(Result,outStream.Size+1);
                FillChar(result[1],outStream.Size+1,0);
                outStream.ReadBuffer(result[1],outStream.Size);
              finally
                FreeAndNil(inStream);
                FreeAndNil(outStream);
              end;
            end;
            function StrToClass(pvStr:AnsiString;pvComponent:TComponent):tcomponent;
            var
              inStream, outStream: TMemoryStream;
            begin
              inStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
              outStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
              try
                if (pvStr<>'') then
                inStream.WriteBuffer(pvStr[1],length(pvStr));
                inStream.Position:=0;
                ObjectTextToResource(inStream, outStream);
               // ObjectTextToBinary(inStream,outStream);
                outStream.Position:=0;
                result:=outStream.ReadComponentRes(pvComponent); //*****Exception Fired*****
                //result:=outStream.ReadComponent(pvComponent);
              finally
                FreeAndNil(inStream);
                FreeAndNil(outStream);
              end;

            end;

            =============
            //test
            procedure TForm1.btn5Click(Sender: TObject);
            var
              lvObj,lv1: TSetting;
              lvStr:String;
              lvArr:TArrayOfInteger;
            begin
              lvObj := TSetting.Create(nil);
              try
                lvObj.intval := 12345;
                setlength(lvArr, 3);
                lvArr[0] := 222;
                lvArr[1] := 333;
                lvArr[2] := 444;
                lvObj.intArr:=lvArr;
                lvStr:=ClassToStr(lvObj);
                RegisterClass(TSetting);
                lvObj.intval:=1;
                lv1:=TSetting( StrToClass(lvStr,lvObj));
                if (lv1.intval>0) then
                mmo1.Text:=lvStr;
              finally
                FreeAndNil(lvObj);
              end;
              // WriteComponentResFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+ 'd.res',self);
            end;

            //First chance exception at $77925B68. Exception class EReadError with message 'Property  does not exist'. Process Project1.exe (23512)

            //First chance exception at $77925B68. Exception class EReadError with message 'Error reading TSetting.: Property  does not exist'. Process Project1.exe (23512)


result:=outStream.ReadComponentRes(pvComponent); //*****Exception Fired*****
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allocating the array when reading it. You could do that like so:

```
procedure TSetting.ReadIntArr(Reader: TReader);
begin
  fIntArr := nil;
  Reader.ReadListBegin;
  while not Reader.EndOfList do begin
    SetLength(fIntArr, Length(fIntArr) + 1);
    fIntArr[high(fIntArr)] := Reader.ReadInteger;
  end;
  Reader.ReadListEnd;
end;
```

The other change that you need to make is to move `intArr` to be a public property. You cannot have it published, and also define a property with the same name in `DefineProperties`.

I am somewhat dubious of your use of `AnsiString`. I would have expected UTF-8 encoded bytes in case of non-ASCII characters. Perhaps you should be using a string stream with the appropriate encoding specified.

Personally I am rather sceptical of using form streaming in this way. I would prefer to use a standard format such as JSON.

Comment: Since the array is being custom-streamed anyway, I would suggest having `WriteIntArr()` write the array count before writing the actual array data. Then `ReadIntArr()` can read the count first and pre-allocate the array one time before then filling it, instead of re-allocating it on each loop iteration. This would also allow removing the `ListBegin` and `ListEnd` markers from the DFM as well.

Comment: If it were me I'd probably opt for `TList<T>`, the `Add` method, and avoid having to write of redundant length info.

Comment: @Remy No, it doesn't do that. It grows the list with a Capacity that can differ from the Count.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating the array before reading data into it.  You were on the right track to have `WriteIntArr()` save the array length and `ReadIntArr()` to allocate the array based on that value, so you should re-enable that logic, eg:

```
type
  TArrayOfInteger = array of integer;

  TSetting = class(TComponent)
  private
    fIntVal: integer;
    fIntArr: TArrayOfInteger;
    procedure ReadIntArr(Reader: TReader);
    procedure WriteIntArr(Writer: TWriter);
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
  public
    property intArr: TArrayOfInteger read fIntArr write fIntArr;
  published
    property intval: integer read fIntVal write fIntVal;
  end;

{ TSetting }

procedure TSetting.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited;
  Filer.DefineProperty('intArr', ReadIntArr, WriteIntArr, true);
end;

procedure TSetting.ReadIntArr(Reader: TReader);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := Reader.ReadInteger;
  SetLength(fIntArr, i);
  for i := Low(fIntArr) to High(fIntArr) do
    fIntArr[i] := Reader.ReadInteger;
end;

procedure TSetting.WriteIntArr(Writer: TWriter);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Writer.WriteInteger(Length(fIntArr));
  for i := Low(fIntArr) to High(fIntArr) do
    Writer.WriteInteger(fIntArr[i]);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
type
  TArrayOfInteger = array of integer;

  TSetting = class(TComponent)
  private
    fIntVal: integer;
    fIntArr: TArrayOfInteger;
    procedure ReadIntArr(Stream: TStream);
    procedure WriteIntArr(Stream: TStream);
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
  public
    property intArr: TArrayOfInteger read fIntArr write fIntArr;
  published
    property intval: integer read fIntVal write fIntVal;
  end;

{ TSetting }

procedure TSetting.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited;
  Filer.DefineBinaryProperty('intArr', ReadIntArr, WriteIntArr, true);
end;

procedure TSetting.ReadIntArr(Stream: TStream);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Stream.ReadBuffer(i, SizeOf(Integer));
  SetLength(fIntArr, i);
  for i := Low(fIntArr) to High(fIntArr) do
    Stream.ReadBuffer(fIntArr[i], SizeOf(Integer));
end;

procedure TSetting.WriteIntArr(Stream: TStream);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := Length(fIntArr);
  Stream.WriteBuffer(i, SizeOf(Integer));
  for i := Low(fIntArr) to High(fIntArr) do
    Stream.WriteBuffer(fIntArr[i], SizeOf(Integer));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the source, it give a demon that how to clone a user class and clone a form . It worked.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TArrayOfInteger = array of integer;

  TSetting = class(TComponent)
  private
    fIntVal: integer;
    fIntArr: TArrayOfInteger;
    procedure ReadIntArr(Reader: TReader);
    procedure WriteIntArr(Writer: TWriter);
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
  public
    property intArr: TArrayOfInteger read fIntArr write fIntArr;

  published
    property intval: integer read fIntVal write fIntVal;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnCloneClass: TButton;
    mmo1: TMemo;
    btnCloneForm: TButton;
    procedure btnCloneClassClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCloneFormClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{ TSetting }

procedure TSetting.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited;
  Filer.DefineProperty('intArr', ReadIntArr, WriteIntArr, true);
end;

procedure TSetting.ReadIntArr(Reader: TReader);
var
  lvIdx: integer;
begin
  fIntArr := nil;
  Reader.ReadListBegin;
  SetLength(fIntArr,Reader.ReadInteger);
  lvIdx:=low(fIntArr);
  while not Reader.EndOfList do
  begin
    fIntArr[lvIdx] := Reader.ReadInteger;
    inc(lvIdx);
  end;
  Reader.ReadListEnd;
end;

procedure TSetting.WriteIntArr(Writer: TWriter);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Writer.WriteListBegin;
  Writer.WriteInteger(integer(Length(fIntArr)));
  for i := Low(fIntArr) to High(fIntArr) do
  begin
    Writer.WriteInteger(fIntArr[i]);
  end;
  Writer.WriteListEnd;
end;

function ClassToStr(pvClass: TComponent): ansiString;
var
  inStream, outStream: TMemoryStream;

begin
  inStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  outStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    inStream.WriteComponentRes(pvClass.ClassName, pvClass);
    // inStream.WriteComponent(pvClass);
    inStream.Position := 0;
    ObjectResourceToText(inStream, outStream);
    // ObjectBinaryToText(inStream,outStream);
    outStream.Position := 0;
    SetLength(Result, outStream.Size + 1);
    FillChar(Result[1], outStream.Size + 1, 0);
    outStream.ReadBuffer(Result[1], outStream.Size);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(inStream);
    FreeAndNil(outStream);
  end;
end;

function StrToClass(pvStr: ansiString; pvCmpToSetProperties: TComponent=nil): TComponent;
var
  inStream, outStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  inStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  outStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    if (pvStr <> '') then
      inStream.WriteBuffer(pvStr[1], length(pvStr));
    inStream.Position := 0;
    ObjectTextToResource(inStream, outStream);
    // ObjectTextToBinary(inStream,outStream);
    outStream.Position := 0;
    Result := outStream.ReadComponentRes(pvCmpToSetProperties);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(inStream);
    FreeAndNil(outStream);
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.btnCloneClassClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  lvObj, lv1: TSetting;
  lvStr: String;
  lvArr: TArrayOfInteger;
begin
  lvObj := TSetting.Create(nil);
  try
    lvObj.intval := 12345;
    SetLength(lvArr, 3);
    lvArr[0] := 222;
    lvArr[1] := 333;
    lvArr[2] := 444;
    lvObj.intArr := lvArr;
    lvStr := ClassToStr(lvObj);
    RegisterClass(TSetting);
    lvObj.intval := 1;
    lv1 := TSetting(StrToClass(lvStr, nil));
    if (lv1.intval > lvObj.intval) then
      mmo1.Text := lvStr;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(lvObj);
    FreeAndNil(lv1);
  end;
  // WriteComponentResFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+ 'd.res',self);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnCloneFormClick(Sender: TObject);
var lvNewForm:TForm1;
lvRes:string;
begin
  lvRes:=ClassToStr(self);
  RegisterClass(TForm1);
  lvNewForm:=TForm1.CreateNew(application);
  StrToClass(lvRes,lvNewForm);
  lvNewForm.Left:=self.Left+50;
  lvNewForm.Top:=self.Top+50;

end;

end.
```